# How to delete data based on value in session variable

Tags: php, session-variables

add.php(When user click add photo)

```
  <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group" id="image">
             <label>Auction Image</label>
<div action="uploadImages.php" class="dropzone" id="uploadImageForm"></div>
 <span class="help-block" id="image-error"></span>
        </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
        Dropzone.options.uploadImageForm = false;
        Dropzone.options.uploadImageForm = {
          paramName: "file",
          maxFilesize: 1,
          acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
          maxFiles: 5,
          dictDefaultMessage: '<img src="images/icon_images.svg" width="100"/><br/><br/>Drop auction image here',
          addRemoveLinks: true,
removedfile: function(file) {
    var name = file.name;        
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'delete.php',
        data: "id="+name,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
var _ref;
return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;        
              }
        };
</script>
```

UploadImages.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config/database.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    exit;
}
else if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $auctionImage = array();
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    if (!$size) {
        header('Content-type: text/json');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(['error']);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $n = 0;
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $imageName = uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/images/uploads/';
        $targetFile =  $targetPath . $imageName;

        $filename  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        // isset id = insert gallery image into database
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO image (user_id, related_id, related_type, url) VALUES (:uid, :id, 'gallery', :url)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':url', $imageName);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else {
            $auctionImage[] = $filename;
        }

    }                                               

    if (!empty($auctionImage)) {
        // record uploaded image name, will store into session
        // store uploaded image into session
        //$_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array();
        $_SESSION["auctionImages"][] = $auctionImage;
    }


}
```

delete.php

```
<?php
$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/images/uploads/';

unlink($targetPath.$_POST['id']);

session_start();
$a = $_POST['id']; 
$key=array_search($a,$_SESSION['auctionImages']);


 if($key!==false){
  unset($_SESSION['auctionImages'][$key]);
  $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array_values($_SESSION["auctionImages"]);

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['auctionImages']); 
}
```

Comment: have u add session_start() before?

Comment: @ChHong Please take a look at my answer. I have included some more points that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem -- What you should do:**

You basically have to populate the `SESSION variable` like this:

```
$_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array(
    "IMG_2923.JPG", "IMG_2924.JPG"
);
```

You're meant to address each element therefore, like this:

`$_SESSION["auctionImages"][$n];`

`$n` is the numbered index value for a particular element in the array. Therefore, if `$n` is 0, the array would return "IMG_29.29.JPG" and if the `$n` is 1, the array would return "IMG_2924.JPG".

However, you are populating the array like this:

```
$_SESSION["auctionImages"][] = array(
    "IMG_2923.JPG", "IMG_2924.JPG"
);
```

If you dump this array, it will give you:

```
array(
    array(
        "IMG_2923.JPG", "IMG_2924.JPG"
    )
);
```

Which is not the behaviour you require.

**Solution**

```
$filename  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if(!is_array($_SESSION["auctionImages"])) {
    $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = [];
}
$_SESSION["auctionImages"][] = $filename;
```

This is more shorter, cleaner and neater.

Also, you can use the alternative array syntax which is `[` and `]`. So, you can declare arrays using `$var = [];` which is shorter than `$var = array();`.

Firstly, the variable `$a` is the text to be searched in the array.

```
$key = array_search($a, $_SESSION["auctionImages"]);

if ($key !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION["auctionImages"][$key]);
}
```

This is the second part of the code. This is all you need to have.

Also, make sure you have started the session by invoking `session_start()` in the top of the file if you haven't done yet.

**A few comments**

- Consider taking a look at the [Unofficial PHP standards here](http://php-fig.org). It would be better if you name your variables in `$camelCase`. Therefore, it would be better to rename `$filename` to `$fileName`.
- Also good job on using `strict comparison` which is `!==`.
- Also, use more meaningful variable names. `$a` does not make sense. Something like `$searchString` would be really meaningful and the code will self-document your code.

**Links**

[`is_array`](http://php.net/is_array) - Returns TRUE if the passed identifier is an array, otherwise returns FALSE.

---

Let's now solve the problem with the full code you have given me. Let's start with `delete.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/images/uploads/';

if(!isset($_POST['id'])) {
    echo "ID has not been defined!";
    exit;
}

$id = $_POST['id'];

unlink($targetPath . $id);

$key = array_search($id, $_SESSION['auctionImages']);

if ($key !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION['auctionImages'][$key]);
    echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r($_SESSION['auctionImages']); 
}
```

Now, let's fix your `UploadImages.php` file:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config/database.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    exit;
}
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    if(!isset($_SESSION["auctionImages"]) && !is_array($_SESSION["auctionImages"])) {
        $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = [];
    }

    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

    if (!$size) {
        header('Content-type: text/json');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(['error']);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $imageName = uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/images/uploads/';
        $targetFile =  $targetPath . $imageName;

        $fileName  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

        // isset id = insert gallery image into database
        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO image (user_id, related_id, related_type, url) VALUES (:uid, :id, 'gallery', :url)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':url', $imageName);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION["auctionImages"][] = $fileName;
        }

    }                                               
}
```

Comment: one more qustion bro..                                                                                                          if i add this line` ( $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array();)` ... when i upload 3 photo it just keep one path inside

Comment: when i add the code inside the upload function cannot to work

Comment: @ChHong Get me the output of `delete.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99398/discussion-between-hassan-althaf-and-ch-hong).

Comment: only when i press upload button nothing happen

Comment: FINALLY...WORK...CASE CLOSE..REALLY THX FOR HASSAN ALTHAF :) ...WITHOUT YOU I CAN DID IT....ANYWAY THXXX

Comment: @ChHong No problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

To use session variables, please add session_start() at the begin of your files, otherwise they aren't used. Secondly you are adding an array into a next array.
so you have to use 
`$_SESSION["auctionImages"] = $auctionImage;`
 or

`$key=array_search($a[0],$_SESSION['auctionImages']);`

Further debugging can be done by print_r($_SESSION); so you can track the contents of this array

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here

```
$_SESSION["auctionImages"][]= $auctionImage;
```

Variable `$auctionImage` itself an array so need not to assign as an array again in `SESSION` variable. Make it as

```
$_SESSION["auctionImages"]= $auctionImage;
```

It works fine for me.

below is the code I worked.

```
<?php
//$filename  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

 $auctionImage = array(); 

 $auctionImage = array('IMG_2923.JPG', 'IMG_2924.JPG', 'IMG_2925.JPG');  // assigning sample variables  // will be IMG_2923.JPG, IMG_2924.JPG and etc

 $_SESSION["auctionImages"]= $auctionImage; // Removed '[]' from your coding

 $a = 'IMG_2923.JPG'; // Assigning for testing purpose
 $key=array_search($a,$_SESSION['auctionImages']);


    if($key!==false)
    unset($_SESSION['auctionImages'][$key]);
    $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array_values($_SESSION["auctionImages"]);

 echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['auctionImages']); // Printing final session value. It prints without the key image name



?>
```

Comment: this code work for me...but when i delete [] in                            `$_SESSION["auctionImages"][]= $auctionImage` , my upload image function cant work ald