# How to delete session variable data based on value

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Firstly, i create one session variable to store the image path

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543012/how-to-delete-data-based-on-value-in-session-variable/?

Comment: You should'nt duplicate questions like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suggested earier,

If you assign like below

```
$filename  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];


 $_SESSION["auctionImages"][]= $filename ; // Here I make changes. Instead of assigining it into multidimensional array I assigned in 2D array
```

Your `SESSION` array will become like

```
Array
(
    [0] => IMG_2923.JPG
    [1] => IMG_2924.JPG

)
```

if you get session array as above, your existing code itself will work

```
$a = $_POST['id']; // user choose to delete photo example value will be IMG_2923.JPG
$key=array_search($a,$_SESSION['auctionImages']);

if($key!==false) {
     unset($_SESSION['auctionImages'][$key]);
     $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array_values($_SESSION["auctionImages"]);
}
```

My Working Code:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // Initializing session

    $auctionImage = time().'.jpg';
    $_SESSION["auctionImages"][]= $auctionImage; // Testing purpose I am creating a image array in `SESSION` using timestamp.

    $a = '1451559040.jpg'; // Reference Key. Here you can assign any existing value. For testing purpose I put some static value.
    $key=array_search($a,$_SESSION['auctionImages']);

    if($key!==false)
        unset($_SESSION['auctionImages'][$key]);

    $_SESSION["auctionImages"] = array_values($_SESSION["auctionImages"]);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION['auctionImages']);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($key); die;

?>
```